# Select data form data base based on language?

Tags: php, html

STEP 1:
data display:

```
$best_prod_tab =mysql_fetch_array($new_prod_res2,MYSQL_BOTH);
```

STEP 2:
function to show data besed on language:

```
function Nomprod($nom){
        if($nom=="fr"){
            echo "$"."best_prod_tab['nomFR'];";
        }
        if($nom=="en"){
            echo "$"."best_prod_tab['nomEN'];";
        }
    }
```

STEP 3:
HTML

```
<p><?php Nomprod($_SESSION['lang']); ?></p>
```

Question:

All what i need to do is show the value of $best_prod_tab['nom+lang'] in HTML from data base,

Anyone can help me or is there any better solution to do the work?!

thank you.

Comment: this is called [**Variable variables ¶**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: I would either change to a `switch` statement or at the very least an `else if` and couldn't you just do `echo $best_prod_tab['nomEN'];` otherwise you could do `$varName = 'nom' . strtoupper($nom); echo $best_prod_tab[$varName];`

Comment: no i can't because i have 5 language and each one has a name in the database for exemple for english => $best_prod_tab['nomEN']; and french $best_prod_tab['nomFR'];

Comment: You can use the $url = 'http://www.example.com';

print_r(get_headers($url)); function to get the acccept language value